# Button working on chrome but not on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I made a button in HTML that work fine on Google Chrome but does not react at all on Firefox.

**My code:**

```js
function fbs_click() {
  var u = location.href;
  var t = document.title;
  window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(u) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(t) + '&s=' + encodeURIComponent(CQuote + CAuthor), 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
}


function rSign() {
  var test = Math.random();
  return test > 0.5 ? 1 : -1;
}
var CQuote = "",
  CAuthor = "";

function getQuote() {
  $.ajax({
    jsonp: "jsonp",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/jsonp",
    url: "https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?",
    data: {
      method: "getQuote",
      lang: "en",
      format: "jsonp",
    },
    success: function(quote) {
      //  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =  
      CQuote = quote.quoteText;
      // document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = 
      CAuthor = quote.quoteAuthor;
      document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = CAuthor;
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = CQuote;
    }

  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  getQuote();
})


var background = document.getElementById('backimg');
var huetarget = 0;
var huecurrent = 0;
var bright = 1;

function abyssmal() {
  background.style.filter = 'hue-rotate(' + huecurrent + 'deg) ';
  if (huecurrent < huetarget) {
    huecurrent += Math.abs(huetarget - huecurrent) / 20
  }
  if (huecurrent >= huetarget) {
    huecurrent -= Math.abs(huetarget - huecurrent) / 20
  }
}
var interval = setInterval(abyssmal, 25);

$("#btnAnimate").on("click", function() {
  huetarget += (Math.random() * 50 + 50) * rSign();
  getQuote();
});

$('#tweet').on("click", function() {
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=" + encodeURIComponent('"' + CQuote + '"   -' + CAuthor), "_blank")
});

$('#facebook').on("click", function() {
  fbs_click();

});
```

```css
/*#myDiv{
  background-color: green;
  transition : background-color 2s,opacity 2s;
    
}

#myDiv:hover{
    background-color : red;
  opacity : 0.5
  
} */

#quotebox {
  font-size: 30px;
  height: auto;
}

#authorbox {
  text-align: right;
}

.box {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

#btnAnimate {
  width: 150px;
}

.share {
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
}

.button {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #333c5b;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}

.background-tile {
  background-image: url(https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/51/3/1513771628-background-1.jpg);
  background-size: 1500px 900px;
  height: 900px;
  width: 1515px;
  padding-top: 270px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#backimg {
  filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="background-tile" id="backimg">
  <div class="box" id="myDiv" style="padding : 50px 50px 10px 50px;width : 45%;border-radius: 5px; background-color : #476870">
    <div id="quotebox">
      <i class="fa fa-quote-left" style="font-size:40px;margin-left : 8px "></i>
      <span id="quote"></span>
      <p id=a uthorbox>-<span id="author"></span>
        <p>
    </div>

    <button class="button quotebutton" id="btnAnimate">get quote</button>
    <button class=" share button fa fa-facebook" id="facebook"></button>
    <button class=" share button fa fa-twitter" id="tweet" style="  margin-right: 25px;"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I doublechecked that only phrasing elements were nested inside the button.

**Question:** Why does the button not react on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Some HTML methodologies are not supported via crossed-browsers.

For example, some features can work on Mozilla and Internet Explorer, but not on Chrome.

However, in this case it's demonstrating the **BODY** tag is overlapping your content. It may be an error with Mozilla in particular with Codepen.io, as W3schools validated that the button feature works on this browser.

Comment: Where do you see a `<body>` tag in his HTML?

Comment: I opened the two browsers and right clicked the button to open "Inspect". It'll highlight the focus as it opens and the DIV corresponding to it. In Chrome, it does not have BODY overlap. In Mozilla, it does. It focuses on the button in Chrome, where it'll blink a particular color on the focused code upon opening it. Mozilla's first focus was on the body. Personally, I think this is an error on the service's end and not your code.

Comment: It's not specific to codepen. I copied his codepen to a stack snippet in the question, and it doesn't work in FF.

Answer (score 0):

You placed everything inside `#backimg`, which has `z-index: -1`, thus sending all its contents below its parent, which is `<body>`. This means that, even though visible, your contents sit below an invisible click-catcher (`<body>`).

Firefox seems to apply the `z-index`, although, AFAIK, the element should be `position`-ed (have a `position` value set to anything except `static`, which is default) for `z-index` to apply. Chrome doesn't apply it, because `#backimg` has the implicit `position:static`.

Closing `#backimg` before opening `#mydiv` fixes the problem and makes your HTML valid. It's not really clear how your layout is supposed to look, but here's my attempt at fixing it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvXXqP

Another problem with your pen had was that it was loading jQuery after Bootstrap's JavaScript, which requires jQuery.

Comment: Oh yeah ! I totally forgot a "z-axis = -1" line, don't know how I could have missed that. Thanks a bunch !